# What does "the guns of spring" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

I saw this expression used in a [Washington Post article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/is-israel-preparing-to-attack-iran/2012/02/02/gIQANjfTkQ_story.html) about the possibility of an Israeli military strike against Iran's nuclear program:

> US officials don’t think that [Israeli prime minister] Netanyahu has made a final decision to attack, and they note that top Israeli intelligence officials remain sceptical of the project. But senior Americans doubt that the Israelis are bluffing. They’re worrying about **the guns of spring** — and the unintended consequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The guns of spring" is a reference to historian Barbara Tuchman's [*The Guns of August*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guns_of_August), and the journalist here used it as a paraphrase to conflate the Arab Spring uprisings with the beginning of the First World War.

Comment: I thought 'the guns of spring' was a generally accepted expression for the upswing in armed hostilities that occur after the slow winter period (travel and supply being more difficult then). But I can't find any reference for that.

Comment: @Mitch: Tropes in this *The NOUN of TIME PERIOD* format have been piggybacking off the Tuchman book title for a long time. Cf. [*The Missiles of October*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missiles_of_October), etc. It is unlikely that a writer from the Washington Post (or his editor) would be unaware of this, and given the penchant of journalists for word-play and reference-bending, I feel my explanation to be all but certain.

Comment: Your answer is the most compelling, but I thought I'd offer my suggestion in the slim possibility there was something before Tuchman.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a figure of speech coined by the author as a complement to the now well-known *Arab spring*. **Spring is in the air**, literally and figuratively. In the recent dominant figurative sense, this construction points to a period of (revolutionary) upheaval.

An unintended consequence of such a development could be a **long, cold winter** that follows.